# Resharper 10 skipping tests in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

I have created unittest using MSTest. I installed Resharper 10.

Now when I want to run my test using resharper, it just skips the tests but I don't see any information as to why it skips them.

On top of that, I created some tests using SpecFlow and SpecRunner, but Resharper doesn't find those tests.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are there specific plugins for SpecFlow and SpecRunner? If so, they might need to upgrade to R#10. About MSTest, is it really marked as *inconclusive* or are they also not discovered?

Comment: I got the specflow and specrunner from NuGet. The tests are discovered, Resharper just marks them as skipped.